# web (html) gui building software

Tags: web, gui, web-development, webgui

I am in need of a software (preferablly free/open source) which facilitates fast and easy creation of html form and controls with proper styling. Similar to **[MachForms](http://www.appnitro.com/)**.

This utility saves me a lot of time but there is one limitation of using it. The source code remains with the server only.

Help me find a capable solution.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for frameworks/toolkits or WYSIWYG-Editors?

Comment: What about these: http://superuser.com/questions/33442/software-for-designing-prototypes-a-raw-design-of-user-interfaces

Comment: @Bobby : I am looking for a WYSIWYG editors

Comment: @random : That post is for planning the interface only. The one that you create before you actually start developing a website.
The solution that I need should be able to make the process of creating forms a breeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found [this](http://www.xara.com/us/products/webdesigner/features/) one. I think this one would definitely help me in designing time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Kompozer](http://www.kompozer.net/)?

Comment: i think it does not support drag and drop support for html controls. Does it ?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's been more than 2 years since I last used a WYSYWYG editor, and I can't remember.. :/

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty for free HTML builders out there. I used [Nvu](http://net2.com/nvu/) and its good or [Coffee-Cup Free HTML editor](http://www.coffeecup.com/free-editor/)